# How to add multiple vsmdi file to one sln

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to add more than one vsmdi file (file that contains test metadata) to a solution.

I'm using one sln with all my testprojects in them.
One vsmdi file was created and it is a solution item, thus on sln level.
Each vsmdi file refers to a testsettings file.

Now my goal is to have multiple vsmdi files, each with their own testsettings files. 
Now adding a testsettings file is no problem (sln -> Add -> New Item... -> Test Settings).
But I can't find how to add a extra vsmdi file. Now I always need to change the testsettings reference inside the one vsmdi file.

The purpose of all of this...
I'm executing vsmdi files using MsTest.exe (on the console line) which fits into my overall system test environment. I use remote execution (with test controller and test agents). This remote execution setting is inside the testsettings file. I want to execute different group of tests, each on a specific group of test agents. The test agents filter can be specified in the testsettings file using roles and attributes. If I would have multiple vsmdi files this would solve my issue.
Ok, I can always use multiple solutions but this rather cumbersome and not my prefered solution.

I'm using VS2010 Premium, SP1 & FP1.

Answer (score 2):

Test lists is what you need:

1) create several TLs

2) create several .testsettings files corresponding to test lists

3) run MSTest from command line specifying both .testsettings (**where** to run tests) and test list (**which** tests to run)

So you get something like `mstest /testmetadata:file.vsmdi /testlist:TestList1 /testsettings:Agent1.testsettings`

Comment: Great tip! The `/testsettings:` argument I overlooked it - wrong help of VS2005. Thank you very much!!!